# undefined local variable or method when using custom scaffolded route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am learning Ruby on Rails and was following a tutorial and scaffolded a CRUD app. I am trying to put link to the add a new entry in the navbar but it's giving the below error:

```
undefined local variable or method `phone_lists_new_path'
```

Here's the navbar code:

```
<%= link_to "List", phone_lists_path, class:"nav-item"%>
<%= link_to "Add contact", phone_lists_new_path, class:"nav-item"%>
```

phone_lists is a folder in View and new.html.erb is a file along with the below ones:

[image]

I guess I am doing something wrong in phone_lists_new_path, but it works in the other links like  phone_lists_path and home_about_path

Comment: If you run `rake routes` do you see that named route?  What is the named route for the `new` method?

Comment: @RockwellRice Thanks, wasn't aware of this cmnd. It was new_phone_list and not phone_lists_new.

Answer (score 1):

It was `new_phone_list` and not `phone_lists_new`, `rake routes` would show the route name.